# How do I fix "Unknown reason -110"?

Tags: google-play-store, installation, system-error, htc-droid-incredible-2

Whenever I try to install/upgrade an application, I get an "Installation Error: Unknown reason -110" message.  What does this error mean, and how do I fix it?

HTC Incredible 2 [Verizon Wireless]

**Edit:**

Updating/installing Market apps.  889MB available internal storage.

Cleared cache and data on both Market & Download manager applications.

Is there anything I can do, besides a hard reset?

Comment: From the Market only or all installs?  How much free space do you have?

Comment: @Matthew: See edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hard reset solved the issue.