# Error 110 while installing apps

Tags: google-play-store, installation, system-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix “Unknown reason -110”?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13605/how-do-i-fix-unknown-reason-110)

I have been getting 'error 110' while installing an app from the playstore. I have an HTC HD Desire. What does this error mean, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache of play store.
Try to log out and log in again into Google account

Similar question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13605/how-do-i-fix-unknown-reason-110)